# Display *browser* loading indicator (like when a postback occurs) on ajax calls

Tags: ajax, browser, xmlhttprequest, loading

example: Go to your Facebook wall, scroll the end of the page, Facebook will load more wall posts **asynchronously**. Or just click on an images in your wall post. The image dialog (with comments and larger image) is loading **asynchronously** as well. (You can see the GET requests with firebug).

But by looking and the firefox tab, you see the loading indicator, just like when a postback occurs.

I know this can be achieved by using an `IFrame` and changing its src. Just like what [iGoogle](http://www.google.com/ig) does. But I'm not sure if Facebook uses an IFrame to load additional wall posts. Is there another way to achieve this?

**Update**: by saying "loading indicator" I did not mean an ajax indicator.
As I mentioned the *browser indicator* (the one at the laft side of a tab showing us if the page is loading) changes to loading like it is a postback.

Comment: Do you want an ajax loading indicator? http://www.bing.com/search?q=site%3Astackoverflow.com+ajax+loading+indicator&go=&qs=n&sk=&form=QBRE

Comment: @jrummell: no, I meant the *Browser* indicator not the ajax one. Please see my update.

Comment: found the answer at: [http://stackoverflow.com/q/8915772/337294][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/q/8915772/337294

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not AFAIK. 
My guess is they probably set the IFrame src to an ajax method and when loaded, they move the content to a div (or another element).

Comment: This answer seems to be outdated in chrome now

Answer (score 5):

It can be done with an iframe. In short, you append a hidden iframe:

```
var $loadingIndicator = $('<iframe src="/loading/" class="visuallyhidden">');
$loadingIndicator.appendTo('body');
```

It has to *load* a page that stalls, never loads. Possibly on the website's own domain since the browser actually shows `waiting for domainname.com` in the status bar.

In the file `domainname.com/loading/index.php` you put:

```
<?php sleep(100);
```

And remove the iframe when done:

```
$loadingIndicator.remove();
```

It's not ideal considering this is actually an additional request. A few reasons:

- your server would have long requests that might have a performance impact
- the browser would use one of the few concurrent connections available, hence possibly slowing down whatever is loading
- **it makes animations stutter** in my case (Chrome 27/OSX, requestAnimationFrame).

via [Slow-loading technique](http://www.obviously.com/tech_tips/slow_load_technique)
 via https://stackoverflow.com/a/3145840/288906

Answer (score 3):

I made a jQuery-based library to handle this which should be a viable solution in some situations (same-origin) and successfully trigger busy indicators in some desktop browsers (modern Chrome and Firefox at least, and oddly, also IE8 but probably not IE9, and definitely not Safari or most mobile browsers).

[Noisy JSON](https://github.com/dtipson/noisy-json)

Basically, I'm using the iframe approach to triggering "busy" indicators, but without artificially hitting a separate "stalled" page: instead, it just uses a custom $.ajaxTransport for passing through a hidden iframe and then parsing the json response back out.  The result is that the browser shows loading indicators that are directly related to the request you're making: no extra http requests. You can  basically install just the plugin then decide which ajax requests should be noisy and which shouldn't just by changing the dataType parameter.

As a side note, the fact that loading content in iframes DOESN'T trigger any UI feedback to the user in Safari and IE9 is just *bizarre*.