# When do browsers show loading indicator?

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, browser, loading, blink

There is some algorithm of showing "loading" indicator in browsers.
There are even some techniques to trigger this indicator, such as:

[Display *browser* loading indicator (like when a postback occurs) on ajax calls](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9314730/display-browser-loading-indicator-like-when-a-postback-occurs-on-ajax-calls)

Is there any documentation of it from any of the browser teams?

I assume it's user-agent business and there is nothing in w3c specs about it.

Is it connected with document readiness (value of readystatechange) and how?
What about xmlhttprequests? Initial resource loading?

Answer (score 1):

This is a pretty good rundown of what browsers do what, based on what sorts of actions [Browser Busy Indicators](http://www.stevesouders.com/blog/2013/06/16/browser-busy-indicators/).

The bottom line is that regular ajax requests rarely trigger busy states (which is generally a good thing) but content loading in iframes will in some browsers.  Generally, the IEs, Safari, and most mobile browsers stay as "quiet" as possible, not even acknowledging page loads in iframes.

I haven't been able to find good discussion or documentation of what the rationale is browser to browser, and it's certainly not a standard that I'm aware of.  Vendors just sort of pick and choose.